# react-native: Not able to set full-width of textbox

Tags: react-native

I'm designing a react-native application based on chat-platform. I'm currently stuck with the UI issue:

[image]

[image]

As you can observe, when I rotate the mobile screen, the textbox does not cover up the full-width space. I'm new to React-native and I tried a lot to fix this issue. I also used `flex: 1` in the `textBox` which seems to work and filled up the whole width of the screen but it hides *microphone icon and add files icon (+)* from the screenshot-1 (i.e when mobile is in vertical position)

Here is the code:

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
    textBox: {
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        flex: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: '#D8D8D8',
        zIndex: 2
    },
    textArea: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexGrow: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff'
    },
    textBoxInput: {
        textAlignVertical: 'center',
        maxHeight: 120,
        flexGrow: 1,
        width: 1,
        // paddingVertical: 12, needs to be paddingTop/paddingBottom because of iOS/Android's TextInput differences on rendering
        paddingTop: 12,
        paddingBottom: 12,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0
    },
```

For the Android devices, the code seems to work fine. It will be great if anyone can help me out with this issue. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

`import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';`

And then do this

`let width = Dimensions.get('window').width`

Now use the width variable as a width css property for the element like this.

```
myElement: {
    width: width
}
```

or this

```
myElement: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
}
```

Make sure you give this to you outermost element to get the full width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many problems involved, however, in my case, to avoid this problems is setting `width` to '100%'. I don't know if it's the most optimal, but it works for me. Parents containers also should have that value, or at least make sure they fill all screen width

Comment: I'm trying to achieve 100% width only. But still, I'm not able to.

Comment: Then it means one of your parents containers isn't filling screens width. some components desn't inherit that prop, for example, you may have one `<View>` with `width:'100%'`, and another `<View>` inside. The last one won't inherit that `width` value, so you will have to specify it again. I might sound trivial, but you should be sure of that first

Comment: Thank you for the help, but above solution also worked. I'll still give you an upvote for helping me out. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you!, I'm glad I still could helped you :)